# Valence Api to get the list of Locale from D2L

Tags: desire2learn

Is there a valence API which can be used to get the list of locale IDs from D2L site. I am using the API to create course which requires an input of LocaleID and I am trying to build some logic which can transform the locale stored in my system to that of D2L system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not currently a Valence API to retrieve the list of locale IDs together with locale names and other meta-data. Additionally, it's possible that only a user with the permissions to use the *Locale Management* admin tool will be able to provide you with the locale IDs that you'll want to use in your calls.

The admin user can go into the Locale Management tool to view the list of locales, click on one to select/edit it, and then, look in the query URL to see what the value of the *id* parameter is: this should be the locale ID.

Comment: Thanks Victor, I actually got the list of locale id by viewing the source of the course management page. However I was looking for a more dynamic way so that I can use with my applicaiton which is intergrating LMS.